# How to check repeated rows from the given SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple query as follows:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT mark, 
    model, 
    model_j, 
    plattform,
    j_id
FROM   jf_version 
WHERE  model_j > 2018 
       AND version = "New"
ORDER  BY marke, 
          model
```

This query generates about 10,000 rows.

I need to check if the generated data contains `j_id` repeated or not.

Can anybody please help me.

Comment: . . Edit your question and show the results that  you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions to get the total count on each row:

```
SELECT DISTINCT mark, model, model_j, plattform, j_id,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY j_id) as total_j_id
FROM jf_version 
WHERE model_j > 2018  AND version = "New"
ORDER BY mark, model
```

You can `ORDER BY total_j_id DESC` if you want to see the duplicated rows first.

Comment: To confirm: If there is duplicate then total_j_id should be more than 1 right?

Comment: @user1687891 . . . Yes.  That is how that window function expression would work.

Answer (score 3):

yu can check if there are duplicates of j_id

```
select j_id from
(
SELECT 
    DISTINCT mark, 
    model, 
    model_j, 
    plattform,
    j_id
FROM   jf_version 
WHERE  model_j > 2018 
       AND version = "New"
)b group by j_id  having count(*)> 1
```

THe returned list of j_id have more than 1 occurence